# Android - Show floating menu for action mode on Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a new menu for action mode. When my webView receives a call to startActionMode I initialize my Menu and this is working ok, see below:

```
 public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)
{
    customSelectionMode = new CustomSelectionMode();
    return super.startActionMode(customSelectionMode);
}
```

Normally, when my menu is called it's a floating menu and that's what I want. My problem occurs with android 4.2 because it's not showing the floating menu, it's creating a action bar menu on top of screen. What could I do to create only floating menu even for old devices?

Tks,

Comment: Posting a basic project with that behaviour would be helpful.

Comment: `Normally, when my menu is called` What's normally? Describe conditions you perceive as normal. ***|||***  [Floating action mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html#TYPE_FLOATING) was introduced in API 23 and was not backported by AppCompat.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want, what's happening on android 4.2 and what's happening on other versions. I would suggest you show upload some screenshots. Maybe you could make a dialog that does what you want?

Comment: Question not clear

Answer (score 0):

Please Check if you are using Activity or AppCompactActivity.  If you use AppCompactActivity then this may resolve your issue with older versions.